# How to make the height of a TextField and a search button equal in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a Flutter app. The app has a `TextField` and an `IconButton`, I want to make their height equal. Here is the current code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: SafeArea(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.yellow,
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: "Input here...",
                        isCollapsed: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 0,
                            style: BorderStyle.none,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Ink(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => {},
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.search)
                    ),
                  )
                ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

You can see that their height is not the same. There are some suggestions on the Internet to make their height equal, but none of them worked for me. Most suggest using a `contentPadding` inside `TextField`, like this:

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    fillColor: Colors.yellow,
    filled: true,
    hintText: "Input here...",
    isCollapsed: true,

    // Add this
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),

    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        width: 0,
        style: BorderStyle.none,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

This seems to work. My complaint with this method is that I need to manually try the correct padding, which is `12` in the above code. Does the number always work on all devices? I'm not sure.

Some suggest using a `SizedBox`, I've tried it, it doesn't work for me either. Here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: SafeArea(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Expanded(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          fillColor: Colors.yellow,
                          filled: true,
                          hintText: "Input here...",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              width: 0,
                              style: BorderStyle.none,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                      child: Ink(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => {},
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.search)),
                      ))
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

My question is, what's the correct way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by removing extra padding from Top and Bottom of TextField, and now both are the same size

```
Row(
            children: [
              const Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,right: 15),
                      fillColor: Colors.yellow,
                      filled: true,
                      hintText: "Input here...",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 0,
                          style: BorderStyle.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              const SizedBox(width: 10),
               Ink(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => {},
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.search)),
                  )
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the icon directly inside your `TextField` instead of separating it.

Put the search icon via `suffixIcon` inside your `InputDecoration()`.

```
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     hintText: 'Input here...',
     suffixIcon: 
     Ink(
     child: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, 
     icon: Icon(Icons.search))
     )
```